# How to publish array of velocities?

Tags: ros, timestamp, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys, so I am very new to ROS and python. Now I understand the following: to publish on a topic, for example Twist() you write something like this and you publish one value for a couple of seconds (4 seconds in this case):

```
   1 #!/usr/bin/env python
   2 import rospy
   3 from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
   4 
   5 def move():
   6     # Starts a new node
   7     rospy.init_node('robot_cleaner', anonymous=True)
   8     velocity_publisher = rospy.Publisher('/turtle1/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
   9     vel_msg = Twist()
  10
  11     vel_msg.linear.x = 0.5
  12     vel_msg.linear.y = 0
  13     vel_msg.linear.z = 0
  14     vel_msg.angular.x = 0
  15     vel_msg.angular.y = 0
  16     vel_msg.angular.z = 0
  17     
  18     now = rospy.Time.now()
  19
  20     while rospy.Time.now() < now + rospy.Duration.from_sec(4):
  21     pub.publish(vel_msg)
  22     
  23 move()
```

But so instead of publishing one velocity for a couple of seconds I want now to publish like an array of velocities. For example vel_msg.linear.x = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]. So every timestep there will be another velocity published until the last value is reached.

How can you do this? And maybe another question: how do you know the timestep that ROS is using between the values of the array? Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366922/how-to-publish-array-of-velocities?/) by [logimaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/64569/logimaker/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, you can create a python code that iterates through the array of velocities you want to send, and you can define a rospy.rate to ensure the velocities are sent at the rate you want them to.  If you need help how to do that, I made this video that might help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rqA7h37k9gw&ab_channel=TheConstruct

---

Originally posted by [rodrigo55](https://answers.ros.org/users/53015/rodrigo55/) with karma: 156 on 2020-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [logimaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/64569/logimaker/) on 2020-12-11**:
Hi, this worked indeed. Thanks a lot!

**Comment by [logimaker](https://answers.ros.org/users/64569/logimaker/) on 2020-12-11**:
I still do have another problem:
So the python code iterates through the array of velocities but now at the same time I also want to subscribe to a topic ( for example /pose ) and save this in a text file until the code has iterated over all the velocities. Because now I am doing this manually in a new terminal with "rostopic echo -p /pose > data.txt" which is not very practical...
Do you know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-03-11**:
Can you please update your answer with main points from the video? If your video goes down or isn't available for certain regions then your answer/solution isn't as useful. Also, some prefer text to 14+ minute video

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We think it's a good idea to define an array of `geometry_msgs/Twist` in a custom message.

```
geometry_msgs/Twist[] twists
```

and use it as follows

```
custom_msg::Twists msg;
msg.twists[0].linear.x = 0.1;
msg.twists[1].linear.x = 0.2;
// ...
```

Custom Message Definition Tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv ...

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-12-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1